# How to call JIRA rest API through Angular 2 rest calls?

Tags: angular, jira, integration

I am creating a middle ware application which is calling JIRA rest API from Angular 2 rest calls

I am using Jira development instance for POC purpose 
Can anyone help ?

Comment: What code have you completed so far?

Comment: I am trying a post request to create jira issue from postman plugin of chrome but it is giving "xsrf check failed jira" error.